# Gathering DNS whois information for large number of typo/squatting domain names

Tags: python-2.7, dns, whois, connection-refused

I am going to gather and analyze the DNS registration information of a large number of domain names. My domain names are such as `bbc.com`, `bbc.com.co`, `bbc.com.a` and `bbc.com.aa`. As you can see, I have typo/squatting domain names of the official web sites such as bbc.com. I am using python whois library and send DNS whois query to these domain names, but for so many of them, I got below message:
Here is my code for sending whois query :

```
try:
    typo_dns_info = whois.whois(typo)
    if typo_dns_info:
        typo_info[typo] = typo_dns_info
        registered_typo.append(typo)
except:
    pass
```

and I got this error for many of the domain names:

```
Socket Error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I searched and I think maybe I need to sleep my program to send DNS query after 1 second. But it did not help me at all. I do not know what is the best way to get the whois information of a `url`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use regular DNS queries to tell if a domain exists. Whois servers typically aren't set up for high volume queries and some limit the rate of queries on a per-IP basis. Regular DNS servers are designed for high lookup rates and will not throw the same errors.

Here's a bit of code to discover registered domains via `dnspython`:

```
try:
    dns.resolver.query(typo, 'A')
    print("%s exists" % typo)
except:
    try:
        x = whois.whois(typo)
        print("%s exists" % typo)
    except:
        print("%s doesn't exist" % typo)
```

Comment: Thank you, but it return something for "redditi.com.CAB" which I can not understand. All of the filed of dns whois query for this typo is empty. But your code says this is exist! Is it possible?

Comment: I think this is because the registrar (Godaddy) is answering WHOIS queries with a more general record. Insert this line after the `x = whois.whois(typo)`: `if 'domain_name' in x: assert x['domain_name'].lower() == typo.lower()` -- that'll make sure the domain listed in the whois record is the actual domain we're interested in.

Comment: Thank you. I also want to check if the web sites for these typo domain names are available or not. Do you know a better way to do that?

Comment: Do you mean check to see if there's an existing web site at (say) www.redditi.com.CAB?

Comment: Domains can exist without being published. So checking DNS for domain name existence is not a good idea.